# How to adapt script to also change file permissions

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that creates duplicates of a sheets template and renames the document, enters some data in A1 and then shares with the person (view only). This is done from a "roster" sheet.

The problem I am having is that when a duplicate is made I still have to go into each document and do 2 things, I would like the script to do these things for me.

1)Allow access to another sheets document (to allow importrange to work!)

2)Change the Sharing settings to "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers"

The script I currently have is:

```
function copyTemplateV2() {

/*DECLARATION OF VARIABLES*/
var settings, template, folder, roster, copy;

/*GENERAL SETTINGS: CHANGE TO SUIT*/
settings = {
    template_ID: 'myid',
    folder_ID: 'folderid',
    roster: 'Script sheet'
}

/*OPEN THE TEMPLATE, THE TARGET FOLDER AND THE ROSTER*/
template = DriveApp.getFileById(settings.template_ID);
folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(settings.folder_ID);
roster = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(settings.roster)

/*READY TO ROLL... GET THE ROWS IN THE ROSTER, FILTER OUT EMPTY ONES AND LOOP THROUGH.. CREATING ONE COPY PER ROW IN THE TARGET FOLDER*/
roster.getDataRange().offset(4, 0).getValues()
    .filter(function (r) {
        return r[0];
    })
    .forEach(function (r) {
        copy = template.makeCopy(r[1] + ' ' + r[2], folder)
            .addViewer(r[4])
            .setShareableByEditors(false)
            .setDescription("class: " + r[3] + "\nFirst name: " + r[1] + "\nLast name: " + r[2] + "\nID: " + r[0])
        SpreadsheetApp.openById(copy.getId()).getSheets()[0].getRange(1, 1).setValue(r[0])
    })}
```

Is this possible by changing the script?

Any/All help greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advanced Drive Service enabled, try below function (pass the ID of the file as the function's argument).

```
/*DISABLE COPYING AND DOWNLOADING*/
function disableCanCopyAndDownload(id) {
var file = Drive.Files.get(id);
file.labels.restricted = true;
Drive.Files.update(file, id);
}
```

Comment: This gives the error : `TypeError: Cannot set property "restricted" of undefined to "true". (line 7, file "Code")`. My answer below works.

Comment: Strange. Worked for me and for the OP. Code below did NOT. Maybe a difference between domain accounts and others ?

Comment: Curious now. This link may shed some light: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration Are you both using v2 or v3 of the API

Comment: Yep. That's probably what causes it. On V2 here. V3 can't be selected from the script editor (advanced services).

Comment: Ha that makes sense